# Integration tests are working fine on eclipse when ran as junit test but throwing exception on server while gradle build

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, gradle, junit5

Integration tests are working fine on eclipse when ran as junit test but throwing exception on server while gradle build.

The Error is coming in all the test cases written,  while all of them are successfully passing in eclipse. The error is as shown below.

```
ModelCatalogControllerIntegrationTest > addTemplateTypeOptions() FAILED
    java.lang.IllegalStateException at DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:132
        Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException at AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1804
            Caused by: org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException at AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:275
                Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException at DialectFactoryImpl.java:100
```

Integration tests are working fine on eclipse when ran as junit test but throwing exception on server while gradle build.

UPDATE: now the test cases are running fine and building successfully on the VM using ./gradlew clean build command But throwing the same above mentioned error for all the test cases while building via Jenkins Pipeline.

ModelCatalogControllerIntegrationTest > getMaturityOptions() FAILED
java.lang.IllegalStateException at DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:132
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException at AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1804
Caused by: org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException at AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:275
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException at DialectFactoryImpl.java:100

ModelCatalogControllerIntegrationTest > updateTemplateDetails() FAILED
java.lang.IllegalStateException at DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:132
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException at AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1804
Caused by: org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException at AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:275
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException at DialectFactoryImpl.java:100
<==========---> 78% EXECUTING [3m 27s]

> IDLE
> :test > 15 tests completed, 15 failed

Comment: dose this gradle build on server has access to database? maybe local run has local db, but on serwer there is no database to connect and run test with. Additionaly full stacktrace or exception message, could be more helpfull, `HibernateException` suggests that problem is related to hibernate but  does not say what was the problem

Comment: Hi @lukwas thanks for the help, this is the error that i am getting in all the 59 cases, same, this is the full stacktrace, but yes server access to database is the thing that slipped from my mind, checking that. Hope it will work then, Thanks for the help.